# How to convert WritableImage to ImageView in javaFX?

Tags: image, javafx, casting, imageview, png

Hello Stackoverflow members, have a great day. Is there a way to convert or cast a writable image object to `ImageView` in order to display it in my program without the need to save the image on a hard drive.

```
WritableImage writable_image = barchart.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);
```

I need something that converts writable_image to `ImaveView` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't convert a `WritableImage` to an `ImageView`. An `ImageView` is a UI component designed to show an `Image`. Since `WritableImage` extends `Image` you don't have to do anything special.

```java
ImageView imageView = ...;
WritableImage writableImage = barchart.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);
imageView.setImage(writableImage);
```